# How to get XSLT working for XML with repeating entries

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have the following problem:
In the xsd given it says:

```
<xs:element name="somevalue" type="ait2:eic" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Field No. 41</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
```

Which for me means the field 41 can be present more than once (field 39 or 42 are only allowed once). I have an example where it actually does (from the xml):

```
<somevalue>12323K</somevalue>
<somevalue>12324I</somevalue>
```

Since its not in its own sequence for-each is not possible (or am I wrong?).
My code looks like this so far (xslt) which just covers the first occurence:

```
<tr>
    <td>41</td>
    <td>Some value</td>
    <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="//somevalue"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

How is it possible to have a repeating group? So each 'somevalue' entry will be present.

THX!

EDIT: Code example

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="#nsc"?>
<xsl:stylesheet id="nsc" version="1.0" xmlns:data="http://www.acer.europa.eu/REMIT/TestTable_V1.xsd" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<data:data>
    <TestTable>
        <TradeList>
            <nonStandardContractReport>
                <settlementMethod>P</settlementMethod>
                <deliveryPointOrZone>12323K</deliveryPointOrZone>
                <deliveryPointOrZone>12324I</deliveryPointOrZone>
                <deliveryStartDate>2022-01-01</deliveryStartDate>
                <deliveryEndDate>2023-01-01</deliveryEndDate>
                <loadType>GD</loadType>
                <actionType>N</actionType>
            </nonStandardContractReport>
        </TradeList>
    </TestTable>
</data:data>
<xsl:template match="/xsl:stylesheet">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="data:data/*" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="TestTable">
    <html>
        <table border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
            <body>
                <tr>
                    <td>40</td>
                    <td>Option strike price</td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="//optionDetails/optionStrikePrice"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th/>
                    <th>Delivery profile</th>
                    <th/>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>41</td>
                    <td>Delivery point or zone</td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="//deliveryPointOrZone"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>42</td>
                    <td>Delivery start date</td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="//deliveryStartDate"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>43</td>
                    <td>Delivery end date</td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="//deliveryEndDate"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>44</td>
                    <td>Load type</td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="//loadType"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th/>
                    <th>Life cycle information</th>
                    <th/>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>45</td>
                    <td>Action type</td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="//actionType"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </body>
        </table>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: What is the expected result in your example? -- P.S. Yes, you *are* wrong about `xsl:for-each`. But it is hard to advise without context - see: [mcve]

Comment: Its a embedded xml file so its kind of hard to take it apart. I will see what I can get working without posting all the code.
The expected result would be that entry 41 is repeated twice in the table.

Comment: Not sure what that means. If you can process the file using the XSLT, then you can also extract it verbatim using the *identity transform* template. And we don't need (or want) the actual file, only a minimized example. And you haven't answered my question regarding the result: if you want to get multiple values, show us how should they appear in the output.

Comment: I edited my first post for the example. I want that 41 gets repeated as often as it is present. Not sure how to do this since its not in its own sequence.

Comment: I am afraid you're not being clear. Do you want a separate row for each `somevalue`? Or do you want to list them in the same cell? Or .. ?

Comment: Yes I want a seperate row for each somevalue.

41 Delivery point or zone value 1
41 Delivery point or zone value 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <alpha>10</alpha>
    <bravo>20</bravo>
    <bravo>21</bravo>
    <bravo>22</bravo>
    <charlie>30</charlie>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>Prima</td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="alpha"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="bravo">
            <tr>
                <td>B</td>
                <td>Secunda</td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <tr>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>Tertia</td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="charlie"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>Prima</td>
      <td>10</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>Secunda</td>
      <td>20</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>Secunda</td>
      <td>21</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>Secunda</td>
      <td>22</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>Tertia</td>
      <td>30</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

rendered as:

[image]

---

Note that the same result could have been achieved using a more elegant approach:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <table border="1">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="alpha">
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>Prima</td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bravo">
    <tr>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>Secunda</td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="charlie">
    <tr>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>Tertia</td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: "*A location step of `.` is short for `self::node()`.*" https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev